# how to identify files modified/touched by chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I would like to find the files on chef client that was touched/modified/created by chef sever.

`chef-client -l` debug command give lot of output.

Comment: It's not chef server that makes these changes, it's chef client :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try [knife-lastrun](https://github.com/jgoulah/knife-lastrun).

It gives you a list of all modified resources.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in Chef 11.8.2 *info* (not debug) logs is very clear stated what resources were not touched. They have **(up to date)** written besides them. Also, if you have log output to console and not into file, then the changed resources will be in green.

Comment: It depends on the use case. For monitoring, follow my answer. For development/debugging follow Draco's.

Answer (score 1):

If you configure and install a [report handler](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_handlers.html) as part of your chef-client run, you can get a list of updated resources (i.e what changed) as well as other goodies that you might find useful.

The `report()` function called in a report handler gets passed a `run_status` object which contains, among other thing:

- `node`, The node on which the chef-client run occurred.
- `all_resources`, A list of all resources that are included in the resource_collection property for the current chef-client run.
- `updated_resources`, A list of resources that were marked as updated as a result of the chef-client run.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list the modified resources in the context of chef, you can install the [chef-handler-updated-resources](https://github.com/jtimberman/chef-handler-updated-resources):

```
$ gem install chef-handler-updated-resources
```

Then appending following code into your `/etc/chef/client.rb` like:

```
require 'chef/handler/updated_resources'

updated_resources_handler = SimpleReport::UpdatedResources.new
report_handlers << updated_resources_handler
```

However, if you do want to list the opened file descriptor underneath chef resources, low level information is required out of the `chef-client` process because of ruby garbage collection. Assume the chef-client runs on linux OS, you can use directory `/proc/$pid/fd` to list all opened file descriptor by given process with a pid. So you can write a custom chef handler with this report method:

```
def report
  Chef::Log.info "File opened by this chef client run:"
  %x( ls /proc/#{Process.pid}/fd -lh | awk '{print $11}').split("\n").uniq!.each {|fd| Chef::Log.info "  #{fd.to_s}"}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2018 the "easiest" way to do this is to run with `-F min` which should reduce the output when running `chef-client -W` or `chef-client` to only a limit set of characters depending on the state of each resource, with a nice summary at the end of only actually/potentially changed resources.

According to a blog post from a couple years ago, you should be able to edit the `client.rb` and add `verbose_logging false` and `log_level :info` to reduce the clutter but I didn't have much luck with that. https://www.frankmitchell.org/2013/04/shush-chef/